# ImportError: cannot import name 'VarcharType' from 'pyspark.sql.types'

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting this error on Google Colab. Is it because I'm using the wrong version?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VarcharType' from 'pyspark.sql.types' (/content/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because VarcharType does not exists yet in spark 3.1.2.

The source code of `pyspark.sql.types` in `__all__` declares the only available types to import:

```py
__all__ = [
    "DataType", "NullType", "StringType", "BinaryType", "BooleanType", "DateType",
    "TimestampType", "DecimalType", "DoubleType", "FloatType", "ByteType", "IntegerType",
    "LongType", "ShortType", "ArrayType", "MapType", "StructField", "StructType"
]
```

Therefore, `StringType` is the alternative:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw VarcharType in documentation for 3.3.0 here and thought I was using the wrong version. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html

Comment: Indeed, I guess it was added in 3.2.0. But your version, according to the initial question message must be 3.1.2.

Comment: Yes, but I tried the other versions and didn't work on them either.